# Comparison of topological spaces

Tags: general-topology

Is there a nice "chain of inclusions" of the following types of topological spaces?
(Like in Algebra we have rings ⊇ commutative rings ⊇ integral domains ⊇ ... ⊇ fields ⊇ finite fields.)

Simply connected, convex, star shaped, contractible.

Feel free to add any type you can place!

Comment: All convex sets are star shaped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are considering subspaces of a topological vector space $V$, say $\mathbb{R}^n$. The notions of simply connected and contractible are very general, while the notions of star-shaped and convex make sense for topological vector spaces.

The chain is convex $\Rightarrow$ star-shaped $\Rightarrow$ contractible $\Rightarrow$ simply connected.

If $X$ is convex, fix a point $x_0 \in X$. Then for any $x \in X$ the line segment from $x_0$ to $x$ is in $X$. So $X$ is star-shaped around $x_0$.

If $X$ is star-shaped around $x_0$, define $H : X \times [0, 1] \to X$ by $H(x, t) = tx_0 + (1-t) x$. This is well-defined because $X$ is star-shaped, so for any $x, t$, $H(x, t)$ is indeed a point in $X$. Moreover $H$ is continuous, $H(x, 0) = x$ and $H(x, 1) = x_0$ for all $x \in X$. So $X$ is contractible.

Finally, contractible spaces are homotopy-equivalent to a point, so they have trivial fundamental group, hence are simply connected.

Comment: So in my notation it would be 

Topological vector spaces ⊇ simply connected spaces ⊇ contractible spaces ⊇ star-shaped domains ⊇ convex spaces ?

Great thanks! Got any to add to the list? (Maybe path connected, connected?)

Comment: I'd rather put it as: among topological subspaces of topological vector spaces, we have the following inclusions... Not all topological subspaces of topological vector spaces are simply connected. As for other inclusions, yes, if you use the convention that simply connected spaces are path-connected (which most people do), then you can add path-connected and then connected at the end of the chain